# Parallelizing accumulative probability distribution

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize my code. The code consists on calculating the accumulative probability distribution function of mvir (counting how many object have a mass, mvir, larger than a given one). However, if I run my code with and without the parallelization I don't obtain the same results.

Here's the code:

```
vector<double>  mvir, contador;
double mlimite;

  for (i = 0; i != mvir.size() - 1; i++)
  {
    mlimite = mvir[i];
    cuenta = 0;
  
  #pragma omp parallel for
    for (j = 0; j != mvir.size() - 1; j++)
    {
      if (mvir[j] >= mlimite)
      {
        cuenta++;
      }
    }
    contador.push_back(cuenta);
  }
```

Comment: Can you show the results with and without parallelization?

Comment: @BartoszKP here's the complete code (with a little change made) and the input file https://github.com/elenaferga/paralellization

Answer (score 3):

This is totally normal to get wrong results with a `parallel for` since the loop increment sequentially `cuenta` causing a **race condition**. You can fix the problem using a **parallel reduction**:

```cpp
vector<double>  mvir, contador;
double mlimite;

for (i = 0; i != mvir.size() - 1; i++)
{
    mlimite = mvir[i];
    cuenta = 0;
  
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:cuenta)
    for (j = 0; j != mvir.size() - 1; j++)
      if (mvir[j] >= mlimite)
        cuenta++;

    contador.push_back(cuenta);
}
```

Note that using a `parallel` section in a hot loop will probably not be efficient. It is likely much better to compute the 2D problem in parallel at once. Moreover, not that the algorithm is not very efficient too. Indeed, you can sort the values to solve this problem in `O(n log(n))` time rather than `O(n^2)` time (where `n = mvir.size()`). Not to mention you can directly create `contador` with the size `mvir.size() - 1` to avoid unnecessary allocations/resizes.

Comment: The vector is already ordered in decreasing mass. I don't understand the thing about creating contador with the size mvir.size()-1

Comment: Ok so you can use dichotomy to find `cuenta` much more efficiently. You can parallelize the encompassing loop but a sequential implementation should already be very fast (and much faster than the parallelized two nested loops). For `contador`, you can initialize it using `vector<double> contador(mvir.size() - 1);` and then use `contador[i] = cuenta;` in the loop. This will be faster since `push_back` is not very fast and will cause many allocations/resizes internally.